# C# managed COM dll in C++ unmanaged project - Strange Entity Framework Problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-c++, com, com-interop

I'm implementing a C# project in a C++ unmanaged solution through COM. the C# project uses an EntityFramework to give back values about the database.

When we call the "Test()" method from an UnitTest C# project in this Solution, everything goes fine. When we call it from the unmanaged C++, an Exception occurs in the called "Test()" method.

The exception:

```
No connection string named 'Entities' could be found in the application 
config file.
```

The location in the unmanaged C++ where we call the "Test()" method:

```
AServer::Server_InterfacePtr p(__uuidof(AServer::Server));
long res = p->Test(); // gives 1337, WRONG: it should give the count of users
```

The called method in the C# project:

```
    public int Test()
    {
        TextWriterTraceListener myTextListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(@"C:\log.txt");
        Trace.Listeners.Add(myTextListener);
        try
        {
            Entities model = new Entities();
            ObjectResult<UserGetAll_Result> res = model.UserGetAll();
            return res.Count;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(e.Message); // writes out "No connection string named 'Entities' could be found in the application config file."
            return 1337;
        }
    }
```

The Unittest method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        var res = server.Test(); // OK: gives the count of users
    }
```

Is there anyway we can solve this? We thought of giving the ConnectionString as parameter in the "Test()" method to use it in the model's constructor, but apparantly `Entities` doesn't accept a ConnectionString as parameter in it's constructor.

The connectionstring has been provided in the C# projects (incl. the unittest) in `App.Config`. The used version of the AntityFramework is 5. The solution targets frameworkversion 4.0.

Methods who don't use the EntityFramework work just fine.

Comment: Put your connection strings config section in the test project!!

Comment: It's not the test project that fails. Like I said "_The connectionstring has been provided in the C# projects (incl. the unittest) in App.Config._". it's the unmanaged project that gets the wrong value.

Comment: Then you can provide the connection string hard coded using the parametrized constructor of the data context:
Entities model = new Entities("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"); If it worked, tell me to add as answer :)

Comment: No, that doesn't work: Visual Studio explicitly gives an error that it is not possible, it only has a defaultconstructor. Like I said: "_but apparantly Entities doesn't accept a ConnectionString as parameter in it's constructor._". This works in EntityFramework version 4.1, but not in 5.

Comment: You should see what is the config file that used for your application, this is a question and solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404988/c-sharp-com-component-fails-to-read-config-when-loaded-into-an-unmanaged-c-app

Comment: Was the last comment useful?

Comment: It gave me some insight, but no information I can practically use. I think because the unittest has a config, it has no problem locating the connectionstring. The unmanaged C++ project doesn't have such system, so I need to find a solution there.